# Read svm data and retrain with more data?

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I am implementing a facial expression recognition and am using SVM to classify given expression.
When I train, I use this command line

```
svm.train(myFeatureVector,myLabels,Mat(),Mat(), myParameters);
svm.save("myClassifier.yml");
```

which will later when I will predict using

```
response = svm.predict(incomingFeatureVector);
```

But then when I want to train more than once (exited the program and start again), it seems to have overwritten my previous svm file. Is there any way I could do read previous svm file and add more data into it (and then resave it ,etc) ? I looked up [on this openCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/ml/CvSVM.html) and found nothing. However, when I read [on this page](http://physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/manuals/opencv/classCvSVM.html); there is a method called CvSVM::read. I don't know what that does/how to implement it.

Hope anyone can help me :(

Comment: No, retraining an SVM is not possible. There are different libraries available for online SVMs, but OpenCV's isn't one of them.

Comment: Are you sure ? So there isn't any solution to this ? :(

Comment: Like I mentioned, some online learning libraries are available. OpenCV's SVM does not support this, and neither does the LibSVM on which it is based.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is incremental learning but unfortunately Support Vector Machines is a batch algorithm, hence if you want to add more data you have to retrain with the whole set again.

There are online learning alternatives, like Pegasos SVM but I am not aware of any that is implemented on OpenCV

Comment: I think that is the best method I can use as of right now.. But this would be troublesome because this means more data to train, it will take more time to train (so far its less than a minute.. but still would have been awesome if I could retrain it.)